# Window server license valid for 52 days only. What will happen after 52 days?

Tags: server, window

I am getting the message - "Window license valid for 52 days."(Screenshot attached below)
I would like to know, will it work after 52 days?

I have installed this server on the virtual machine.
If I will not access this server after the 52 days, then I will take a backup of data from it.

Please help. Any suggestion is helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,

Parvesh.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but it will automatically reboot every hour.
"Any suggestion is helpful." => Get a valid license from Microsoft.